# How or can I use JavaScript to append a div tag after the html or body tags?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, skype

For a very specific reason I would like to know if you can add a tag either after the `body` or `html` tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>

<!-- Can I add a tag here? -->

</html>

<!-- Can I add a tag here? -->
```

I have noticed this is what the Skype plugin for Chrome does, and would like to know how they did it. I have attached a screenshot of proof.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can append some element after the body element as such:

```
var e = document.createElement('a');
document.body.parentNode.appendChild(e);
```

Attempting to insert an element which is a sibling of the `html` element results in the following error:

[image: Error]

Comment: Appending an element after the `body` element makes the document invalid (non-conforming), as it violates the content model of the `html` element. It probably still works, but I would not do so unless I knew I have a problem that cannot be solved otherwise.

Comment: I would typically agree. I think it's interesting that the Skype plugin does that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, KPthunder's sample springing to mind. You can also just rewrite the content of the entire document and reload it. Ugly, and brutal, but it works.

Note, however, that browsers are not required to honor the element. As mentioned, it's noncompliant, and therefore not guaranteed to work across all browsers. It'll likely work in IE. But that's IE. And IE supports *everything.* </eyeroll>

I've actually encountered elements that appeared both before and after the HTML element itself, and it wasn't intentional (*cough*). Likely, this is the case here. My advice to you is, don't try to repeat it.

Comment: This is a comment telling you that this should be a comment. /meta

Comment: I refer you to the first paragraph. "You can also just rewrite the content of the entire document and reload it." Also, please note that it's fairly important to point out that in most cases what he's trying to reproduce (in my experience) is neither intentional nor a sign of quality development.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for jQuery but, for example

```
$( "<p>Test</p>" ).insertAfter( "body" );
```